# Access global variables from exported function

Tags: node.js, express, typescript

I have a file `config.ts` which simply exports a config object:

```
const config = {
    baseURL: <string> 'http://example.com',
};

export default config;
```

I have another file called `methods.ts` which imports the config object and exports a function which uses this config object.

```
import config from './config';

export function someMethod() {
    let url = config.baseURL;
    ...
}
```

I'm calling this `someMethod` from inside the express router:

```
import { someMethod } from '../methods';

router.get('/something', function(req, res, next) {
    let x = someMethod();
    ...
});
```

when this `someMethod` is called the `config` variable is `undefined`. It seems `someMethod` can't see the imported data from the same file when it's called later. What would be the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Node wraps your module in an IIFE called [the module wrapper](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper) so even though it is global in your module, its actually still local.

If you want to have access to `config` outside of your module, you'll need to explicitly export it.

```
function someMethod() {
    let url = config.baseURL;
    ...
}
export { someMethod, config };
```

---

If `config` is actually common to a number of files, you could use [Dependency Injection](https://blog.risingstack.com/dependency-injection-in-node-js/) and move `config` into the file containing your router that needs config.

Change `someMethod` to accept `config`

```
// methods.ts
function someMethod(config) {
  let url = config.baseURL;
  ... 
}

export { someMethod };
```

Import `./config` in your router instead and pass `config` into `someMethod`

```
// router
import config from './config'
import { someMethod } from '../methods';

router.get('/something', function(req, res, next) {
    let x = someMethod(config);
    ...
});
```

Comment: I want the `config` to be available inside `someMethod`. re-exporting it from that file doesn't make any sense...

Comment: @KingJulien In my opinion, the better way to approach this would be to inject the config from your router

Comment: @KingJulien updated my answer to include an example based on my last comment

Comment: Yeah, that's one way to go... and I think it's not as bad as it first seemed to me...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do

```
import config from './config';
var Config = config
export function someMethod() { console.log(Config) }
```